# Issue with Azure AD hybrid join and on-prem MFA server

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

We are having an issue with our hybrid joined computers and users using on-prem MFA. The hybrid SSO is not working when the user is MFA enabled (users are not logged into Office apps and OneDrive). Azure MFA or no MFA allows the SSO to work. Where should I start troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are using the "Remember Multi-Factor Authentication" setting, but it isn't included in MFA server. That feature is not compatible with the KMSI (keep me signed in) feature of ADFS (used with MFA Server).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-mfasettings

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216840-security-and-compliance/suggestions/31120336-remember-multi-factor-authentication-for-devices-t